Does the Eruv Tavshilin allow one to do a preparation that one can do on Shabbat?
If one made an Eruv Tavshilin, may he do a preparation on Yom Tov, if the act that he is doing can anyway be done on Shabbat (unlike, say, cooking) and doesn't need to be done on Friday?

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%98_%D7%98%D7%95
